# Numbers given: 2, 3, 6, 15, choice of answers: 24, 25, 36, 64?

Tags: number-sequence

Math question, numbers are

```
2. 
3. 
6. 
15
```

Choice of answers given are

```
A.24
B.25
C.36
D.64
```

What is the correct choice please?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Is A supposed to be 42?

Comment: _"...appears to be a mathematics problem..."_ No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

with no context, a variety of possible sequences produce these numbers.

For example, I multiply 2 by 1.5 to get 3, 3 by 2 to get 6, and 6 by 2.5 to get 15. So the next term must be 15 x 3 or 45. But that's not one of the listed answers.

Ok, perhaps I add 1 to 2 to get 3, then add 3 to that to get 6, then add 9 to that to get 15, so for the next term I must add 27 giving 42. But that's also not one of the listed answers.

That makes this a "guess the possibly convoluted series of operations I was thinking of" puzzle, and significantly underspecified. These sometimes work in context where you know all the sequences involve multiplying, or squaring, or whatnot, but generally don't work just out of the blue such as on this site.

Comment: Your second sequence can also be expressed as  $F(n) = F(n-1) * 3 - 3$